# Android navigation with toolbar overflow returning null

Tags: android, android-navigation

Edit: see my partial solution below - but it is not satisfactory. So please do answer!

Original: I am using android navigation framework and have a custom toolbar. On the menu setup I arrange some click listeners, and can navigate successfully to other fragments using things like

```
[FragmentA]Directions.Action[FragmentA]To[FragmentB] action =
                [FragmentA]Directions.action[FragmentA]To[FragmentB](args);
action.setArgs(args);
Navigation.findNavController(binding.[myToolbar].findViewByID([myMenuItem])).navigate(action);
Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.[FragmentBLayout]);
```

*whenever* myMenuItem is an actionView in the toolbar,

But when I have an overflow popup menu in my toolbar (ie those menuitems with showAsAction=never), the findViewByID in the third line returns null. That is, I can't access the popup menu views - they always return null. This is so whether I use my binding or getActivity().findViewByID.

Therefore the navigation fails.

Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have partially 'solved it' by using a) MenuProvider and b) inserting

```
Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.[NavContainer]);
```

as in

```
binding.[myToolbar].addMenuProvider(new MenuProvider() {
    @Override
    public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
         menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.vocab_test_menu, binding.vocabTestToolbar.getMenu());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
         NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.fragmentContainerView);
         switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
               [cases] SomeOption(navController)
    }
});

...

SomeOption(NavController navController) {
 [FragmentA]Directions.Action[FragmentA]To[FragmentB] action =
                [FragmentA]FragmentDirections.action[FragmentA]To[FragmentB](args);
        action.setArgs(args);
    navController.navigate(action);
    Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.[FragmentBLayout]);
}
```

Before I was just using `binding.[myToolbar].inflateMenu([myMenu])` and  `binding.[myToolbar].setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> { switch [cases] })`. As far as I can get to grips with the documentation, using a menuprovider is superior - it has better lifecycle properties, but I'm not entirely sure about that - maybe someone could comment about that?

Edit: this is not entirely satisfactory, since it will trigger all menu items, regardless of whether I want them to navigate or not! If all of them are for navigation, then the above works, as long as all the navigation is written in for each menu case. But if one of the menuitems is not for navigation, my 'solution' will not work!